# Happiness in devastation

Tags: sound-effects-recording

Yebo good people!
Not strictly a question as much as posted more as an inspiration for those who might enjoy it!

The TV-set was sentenced to sledgehammer for the viscous crime of sending Days Of Our Life and 7th Heaven to innocent unsuspecting viewers.

[vimeo]36985816[/vimeo]

Comment: Ha, great crash sound from it.

Comment: Did you take part in this? I did the exact same last summer with a TV approximately the same size, using an NT1-A and AT8015. The NT1-A flipped out and didn't record anything... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwzLkljuO0

Comment: @Brendan - Thanks, I'm very happy with what we got :-)

@Justin - Wonderful clip! And yup, I'm the one holding the boom. The girl swinging the hardware is my assistant Andréa, and my dad holds the iPhone :-) It was tricky to choose mikes. After all, we didn't exactly have a second take, so I went the safe way with a Sennheiser MKH 40 on boom and a Shure SM57 on stand, recorded on my Fostex FR2. I was extremely pleased with the result :-)